# Cómo puedo imprimir los valores de Arreglos bidimensionales con filas de distintas longitudes

Tags: java, array, java-8

Estoy tratando de entender como funcionan pero aveces me confundo

```
int [][] miArray = {{1,2},{3,4,5}};
```

Esta declaración que vi en un libro me confunde un poco por que no sé si es un `array` `2x5` o `2x3` el punto es como puedo imprimirlos en la consola trate de hacerlo así

```
for(int i = 0; i <=1;i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j <= 2;j++) {
        System.out.printf("miArray1[%d][%d] : %2d%n",i,j,miArray[i][j]);
     }
}
```

Pero eclipse me envía a una ventana de `debug`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Java una matriz bidimensional no es más que una matriz de matriz. por lo cuál se le puede asignar una cantidad no determinada de elementos a cada matriz, Por ejemplo

```
int [][] miArray = {{1,2},{3,4,5}};
// es equivalente a tener 
int miArray [][] = new int[2][];
miArray[0] = new int[2];
miArray[1] = new int[3];
```

Cada "fila" es una `array` de elementos con una cantidad que puede o no ser fija. Dicho esto para poder imprimir sus valores bastaría con dos `for`  anidados sería

```
for(int i = 0; i < miArray.length;i++) {
    // accedemos al length del array actual index i
    for(int j = 0; j < miArray[i].length;j++) {
        System.out.print(miArray[i][j] +"\t");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Adicionalmente tenemos un método de `Arrays` para imprimir.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(miArray));
```

Con *Java8* , recurrimos a `streams` , iteramos con un `forEach` e imprimimos el `array` mediante `toString()` de la clase `Arrays`. *(pueden haber más formas)*

```
Arrays.asList(miArray).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
```

Comment: no soy de los que elogian tanto pero vaya  tal vez es muy fácil para ti pero algún día te alcanzare en relación a conocimiento muchas gracias por ayudarme ahora si puedo avanzar con el curso enhorabuena!

Comment: Una cosa, al principio, donde inicializas el array bidimensional dices "es equivalente a tener" y no porque con int [][] miArray = {{1,2},{3,4,5}}; además de indicar el tamaño de los array les está dando valor y al hacer int miArray [][] = new int[2][];
miArray[0] = new int[2];
miArray[1] = new int[3]; no. Por lo demás perfecto =)

Answer (score 0):

Te manda a un debug porque accedes fuera del array en la primera fila:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= 2;j++) {
```

Accedes a la posicion miArray[0][2] que no existe.

Tambien lo puedes recorrer con bucles foreach:

```
    int[][] miArray = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};
    for (int[] fila : miArray) {
        for (int elemento : fila) {
            System.out.printf("miArray1 : %2d%n", elemento);
        }
    }
```

Siempre y cuando no modifiques el valor del elemento ni necesites los índices de la posición.