# ¿Como imprimir una matriz rectangular? java

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola quisiera saber como puedo imprimir esta matriz de 2x3 ya que siempre la imprime de 2x2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

double notas[][]= new double[2][3];
int i;
int j;

    String acum="\n";
for(i=0;i<notas.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<notas.length;j++)
    {
        notas[i][j]=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese una nota"));
         acum= acum+" "+notas[i][j];
    }
    acum+="\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,acum);

}
```

Comment: `notas[i].length`en el segundo loop

Comment: Existe una [pregunta relacionada,  casi duplicada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131104/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-imprimir-los-valores-de-arreglos-bidimensionales-con-filas-de-distint) solo que el tipo de dato cambia a  entero. Puede ayudar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo menciona  alo Malbarez te falta notas[i], por lo que solo estás tomando la cantidad de filas y no la de columnas.

```
        for (i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < notas[i].length; j++) {
```